# iPad short animation using image sequence

Tags: objective-c, performance, ipad, uiimageview

I have red several post on this but I haven't seen anything convincing so far.
Suppose I just want 3 small animations with transparency where you have the following images,

**Animation 1 - 15 png images, Dimension of 322*366.**

**Animation 2 - 3 png images, Dimension of 930*480.**

**Animation 3 - 2 png images, Dimension of 83*364.**

I did these 3 animations using UIImageviews animationImages and it has a slight delay. I just wanna do a couple of seconds animation.

1. Is there a better way to do it other than playing a video?.
2. Does anyone know how **sequence of images** on the iPad, regarding performance etc?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `animationImages` property of `UIImageView`.

```
 // create the view that will execute our animation
 UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
 // load all the frames of our animation
 campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.gif"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.gif"], nil];

 // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
 campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
 // repeat the annimation forever
 campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [campFireView startAnimating];
 // add the animation view to the main window 
 [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

[Taken from Animating with the UIImageView](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html)

Comment: When we add images to array saying [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"], images will get cached right?. I'm concerned about the app memory. And also I did exactly like that and I get a half a second delay for the first time I run the animation. After that it is fine.

Comment: @deamonsarea: if we use animation with imeges definalty it's going to be the heavy memory consumption operation ... need to be taken care of memory and release it when not required ...

Comment: How do I clear the cached images?. Is there a specific function for that?.

Comment: Even though you release your view, the images will be cached and u'll finally face a memory crisis. Check this out,

http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/

Comment: I sorted the problem using a NSTimer. It did the trick.Thanks Jhaliya for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -initWithContentOfFile: function instead of -imageNamed: if you don't want to cache the image and not being able to retrieve that memory back.

The problem is that when you'll start your animation (`[campFireView startAnimating]`), the system will uncompress and keep ALL the images of campFireView in memory. It will definitely take a lot of memory space...

Note that this memory space will be properly released when calling `[campFireView release]`